# Magento 2.1 Save Credit Card extension

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods

Magento 1.7 or 1.9 have the facility of Save CC but it is not in Magento 2.
[image]

Please guide to create or if there are any extension available?

Comment: It's against PCI standards to keep customer credit card info in your database. You can find the reasons why PCI Council restricts this in the post - http://blog.emagicone.com/2015/12/why-credit-cards-can-not-be-charged.html

Comment: have any option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Saving credit cart info itself inside your DB is a very bad idea, as noted above by Vishwas.

However, if you have valid reason (e.g. a need to implement recurring payments or auto-complete for the user), you can use the best available replacement: Payment methods which implement the Magento Vault interface. simply put, these save the credit card and customer info on their end and provide you with a reusable token (more on that [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/vault/vault-intro.html) ). I am fairly sure this feature is provided by braintree for magento2, and maybe some others as well (try googling "How is vault payment providers list gathered Magento 2" for more details on that).

Worth mentioning: [this module](https://store.paradoxlabs.com/magento2-authorize-net-cim-payment-module.html) also claims to provide mentioned functionality.

Answer (score 1):

What payment method will you use in your magento 2?
Braintree implements it out-of-the-box (but only can store credit card data when place order) using Magento Vault.

If you use the extension from ParadoxLabs for Authorize.Net you can allow customers to add/modify/delete credit cards in customer dashboard. This options doesn't use Magento Vault. It works with its own table.

Both options store the credit card data in Braintree and Authorize.Net servers respectively and you get a token in Magento for each credit card.

Answer (score 0):

It's against PCI standards to keep customer credit card info in your database. You can find the reasons why PCI Council restricts this in the post - http://blog.emagicone.com/2015/12/why-credit-cards-can-not-be-charged.html

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 doesn't support saving CC information. To save CC data need to create new payment method using custom module.There are few extensions available in market to fulfil your requirement.  Please checkout the url : https://www.instamojo.com/gpsolutionsglobal/magento2-save-card-details/